# Autodesk Forge - Capture the image of the issue location

Tags: autodesk-forge

I saw that when generating a PDF using BIM360, an application sends the PDF by email and in the PDF content there is a screenshot of the location that the issue was registered in, I am creating a customized report that would be necessary to have the same type information, in this case, a capture of the issue's location, has anyone managed to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to take a snapshot from the screen where the Issue is visible, something like described at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/screenshot-markups